# High-end PC graphics circa 1990?

Tags: graphics, ibm-pc, video

I remember CAD being a major driver for PCs with high-end graphics cards; specifically AutoCAD was rising quickly in popularity around 1990 as PCs were able to compete with very costly CAD workstations.

My memory about the high-end graphics cards of the time is sparse. I do remember the TI TARGA compatible cards, which were popular for photo-realistic graphics, and I think could work with AutoCAD as well. And I remember Number Nine cards being highly regarded by some AutoCAD users.

I am mainly interested in the period from 1988 to 1992-3. At that time, SVGA was new (VGA even somewhat new), and lower-cost video cards lacked the resolution and performance desired by AutoCAD users. I think they were aiming for 1024x1024 pixel resolution with accelerated 2D.

So, what were the most capable/popular high-end video cards for CAD on PC's at this time, and what were their capabilities (resolution, color depth, monitor freq., VRAM capacity, etc.)?

Comment: I vaguely recall the Tseng Labs ET3000/4000/6000 chipsets being a big deal at the time, but I don't know if they were used in high-end workstations.

Comment: I know AutoCAD is almost unique in using the accelerator functions built into the IBM 8514, but I've no idea as to its actual performance or popularity, alas.

Comment: In 1990 high-end like you described either meant higher resolution and/or colour depth than VGA (and not necessary VGA compatible, so not SVGA, like with the Truevision TARGA) or alternatively 2D accelerators like with the IBM 8514/A and its many clones.

Comment: My memory says that Diamond Stealth cards were big then. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diamond_Multimedia#Stealth

Comment: @LAK that was at the end of the period Brian is interested in — Stealth cards were VL-bus or PCI cards, so 1992 onwards.

Comment: It was possible to get specialty equipment that would go to 1Kx1K mono and I think maybe even 2Kx2K. It was used for medical imaging mainly. Nobody else could afford it as I think the highres monitor was just as expensive if not more expensive than the video card, if I recall correctly.  You tended to buy them as subsystems card+monitor from a single source. IIRC.

Comment: @davidbak: I worked on a medical imaging platform in 1989 which was 1024 x 1024 x 8-bit grayscale.  However, it was based on Sun-3, not PC.

Comment: Please clarify - are you talking about high resolution or high colour depth (for the time) ?

Comment: @Criggie I'm talking about whatever was most important to AutoCAD users. Not having been a user, myself, I can only speculate on what they valued highest. My guess would be resolution and re-draw speed, but I'm happy to be corrected.

Comment: @BrianH My answer below assumes resolution > colour depth.  If it misses the mark please comment and I'll delete it.

Comment: @Criggie for CAD, resolution does trump colours, but by 1990 CAD users had 1024 horizontal pixels and at least 16 colours, HGC wasn’t relevant.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Basic level - 8514/a clones, like ATI Mach 8 (1990, up to 8-bit color, up to 1 meg VRAM, up to 899$) - [see](http://www.vgamuseum.info/index.php/cpu/item/82-ati-38800-1-mach-8-graphics-ultra-8514-ultra-graphics-vantage)

Medium level - TIGA-based video accelerators, especially for CAD. [see](http://www.vgamuseum.info/index.php/cards/itemlist/category/38-texas-instruments-graphics-architecture-tiga)

High end - CAD/PostScript accelerators like [SPEA Fire](http://www.vgamuseum.info/index.php/component/k2/item/540-spea-fire) with i860 CPU onboard.

Early solution - miro GRAPH 510 on Signetics SCC63484 ACRTC chipset, 1986, 2 meg VRAM. [see](http://www.vgamuseum.info/index.php/cards/item/601-miro-graph-510)

Comment: Did any video cards with that Signetics chipset have the full 2 MiB of Video RAM?

Comment: Some impressive cards there. I had forgotten about the i860 as a graphics accelerator.

Answer (score 6):

I think the [Metheus UGA 1228](https://books.google.com/books?id=cTAEAAAAMBAJ&pg=PT19&lpg=PT19&dq=Metheus%201224&source=bl&ots=81o0Ej6qLu&sig=ACfU3U3y9m_lzbKH-myKVLEbdg_nazzOkw&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj5-dr7xeniAhUFsJ4KHbdsDncQ6AEwCXoECAUQAQ#v=onepage&q=Metheus%201224&f=false) ($3,995 in February 1990, equivalent to $7,750 in 2018) qualifies as high-end. It supported 2 MiB of Video RAM for a maximum resolution of 1,280×1,024 pixels in 256 colors, when most other graphics cards at the time topped out at 512 KiB and 1,024×768 in 16 colors.

Comment: 1280x1024 at 8bpp is only about 1.31 MB. You can neatly fit 1600x1200 at 8bpp into 2 MiB (it requires 1.92 MB, plus whatever, if anything, is needed in video RAM for color look-up tables and such).

Comment: @aCVn That's true but it appears that color 1600x1200 monitors didn't arrive until around 1992 or 1993.

Comment: I think I have/had one of these Metheus cards. I thought it was just a CGA card on account of the 9-pin connector but it had a standard text font that looked similar to what you get on a Sun so I always liked it for that.

Comment: Remember these cards also stored "display lists" internally so redraws were instantaneous and not as many regens were needed. This could be the primary purpose of the extra memory above what was required for 1280x1024x8bpp.

Answer (score 0):

High-res monitors (1024 and above) were not commonly available at consumer or office store prices back circa 1991.  So several companies, Sigma Designs for one, manufactured and sold custom monitors and matching graphics card combos.  Custom yokes and magnetics, etc. in addition to a graphics card with a custom ASIC or gate array.

Answer (score 0):

In 1989 I had a "high resolution" video card for the time - but it was two-colour being black or white.

The Hercules graphics adaptor was capable of all normal text resolutions, and could display 720x350 pixel image.   While not a lot of colours, its a respectably high resolution for the time.

Remember that one of your points in the question is **CAD** where high resolution easily trumps a couple of colours.

The Hercules card was an 8 bit ISA card, and was probably full length in earlier iterations, shrinking down to 8 bit card size by around 1990.  Often doubled with a parallel port on the board, they had 64 kilobytes of video memory, compared to 16 kbytes for CGA or 4 kbytes for the IBM Monochrome Display Adapter.

Power users could run a herc monitor and a VGA monitor side by side too, for early dual-screen PCs.

Further information   https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hercules_Graphics_Card

Comment: In 1989 the Hercules Graphic Card was the exact opposite of high-end PC graphics. It was for people who couldn't anything better.

Comment: @RossRidge Not sure if we're at cross purposes here - a high resolution 720x350 was well above what CGA could offer, and a higher res than EGA.  Released in 1987, VGA was simply not able to exceed 720x350 until SVGA extensions made 800x600 possible.

Comment: Sorry, if I wasn't clear.  I meant to say that in 1989 that Hercules graphics were for people who couldn't afford anything better.  Also for CAD, VGA's 640x480 16 colour graphics were a massive improvement over Hercules 720x350 mono